# Facebook JavaScript SDK gets user name without authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I have a Facebook canvas iframe application that uses the JavaScript SDK. How do I get the user's name without them having to authorise the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

When Facebook calls your page, it's done by POSTing into an iframe and you get a [signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) which lacks most data if the user hasn't yet to authorize your applications, as it says in the documentation:

> Some fields and values, the user_id and oauth_token for example will
>   only be passed if the user has authorized your app

The [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) request require you to supply an active access token, otherwise you should get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2500
  }
}
```

(You can check that in the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me); just remove the access token before you try.)